# Can I limit the amount of mobs within a chunk?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Is there a plugin to limit the number of mobs that occupy a chunk in minecraft?

I'm concerned about players breeding or afking a mob spawner and bringing the server down by over concentrating mobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also [EntitySuppressor](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/entitysuppressor/), but I don't know if it supports per-chunk settings.

Comment: Looks like it does.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [NoSpawn](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/nospawn/) has got some kind of limit, but I think it's server-wide, not per chunk.
It might be able to help with your problem though.